# Kali linux sniff traffic using lan tp link router

Tags: android, wireshark, kali-linux

Hey I am trying to monitor traffic on my phone using kali with wireshark and ettercap. But I am facing some issue.

My problem I have a tplink router and my android is connected using wifi. and my kali is install on my pc which is connected using lan wire.

Whenver I try to scan for host in wireshark or ettercap it just scan only one pc. Is there any way to sniff all connected device using any sniffing tool. I am new to kali this is strange situation for me. I just want to monitor my android app traffic using kali for testing of my app if it is secure or not I need to check all the post request made by an API from my app are encrypted or not.

I don't know how to do port mirroring or will it help my router does not have that. On kali is there any method or tool by which I can sniff the network to see traffic in my case my pc which has kali is connected using lan to router and my device is connected using wifi of same router.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is quite hard.  The issue you are facing is that the traffic is not being directed through the box runing Kali.

In order to fix this you would need to set up your Kali box to act as an ethernet router and then assign a static IP address to the phone and Kali Linux interface, and point the default gateway on the Android box to the Kali router.
Unless the Kali box has multiple ethernet interfaces you will also need to handle the fact that the data is traversing the same ethernet port twice.

An easier solution would be to sniff the traffic on the server side - you don't need Kali linux to do this - any Linux or BSD variant can do it using tcpdump.